# Is there a way to have the Staff Code and Name on a Single Row in an SSRS table

Tags: sql, report, reportingservices-2005

Is there a way to have a table in SQL Server Report Builder (its the only version of SSRS i have the option of using) that looks like the below?

I am grouping by Parent Group: staff_code and Child Group: Client_code. I cannot get the staff_code and Staff_name on its own row, and cannot get the Client_code and Client_Name on its own row and still have the grouping work.

[image]

The only  way i can get it anywhere close is like this, but it keeps repeating the Staff Code and Name on each line for each client:

[image]

If i add child_code to the row grouping under staff_code, it creates a Client_code column and I dont want a column:

[image]

Comment: It looks like you have the Staff and Client in the same grouping - there should be two Grouping levels. A pic of your Design view would be helpful with the table selected so the left-hand grouping levels are displayed (the parenthesis-looking lines for grouping).

Comment: I added a picture of the Group properties. If i add a Parent or Child group for Client-Code under Details1, it creates a column for client_code and I dont want a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding group row for staffcode, checkbox for Group Header.